# Angular lazyload child routes with outlet

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have tried to reproduce my error in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fppmae)

**What I try to accomplish**

I am trying to have a route with a dynamic parameter, and have sub routes of that parameter. I want this module to be lazyloaded. 
I have made a working solution for the dynamic parameter using the `:id` definition in the route definition.

I want the child routes to output in a different router-outlet.

Specifically I want a component (`UserComponent`) loaded on the route `user/:username` - if the path is empty after the `:username` I want to load `UserDefaultContentComponent` in the router defined inside the `UserComponent` - If the path is having an extension like `user/some-user/other` I want the `UserOtherComponent` to load in the outlet. But ALWAYS have `UserComponent` loaded on `user/:username` - example `user/some-user`

**Theories of what is breaking this**

So the configuration I have created I am getting errors when I try to resolve the child routes. I was able to load `UserComponent` on empty user path without the lazyloading.

I also think having static subroutes to a dynamic `:username` route is caursing the issue.

**The configuration**

For full code see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fppmae)

Below is the code I find relevant. Please comment if I am missing something here:

App Routing (Root routing)

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: AppComponent, data: { state: 'home' }},
    { path: 'user/:username', loadChildren: './user-module/user.module#UserModule'}
];

export const appRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

User routes (child routing)

```
const USER_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: UserComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: UserDefaultContentComponent, outlet: 'user-outlet'},
      { path: 'other', component: UserOtherComponent, outlet: 'user-outlet'},
    ]}
];

export const userRouting = RouterModule.forChild(USER_ROUTES);
```

Imports of those is in the UserModule & the App module. I am also exporting the child routes from the User Module.

UserComponent - contains the named router outlet:

```
<div>
  THIS IS A USER
</div>

<router-outlet name="user-outlet"></router-outlet>
```

**Urls to test**

This url should load UserOtherComponent: `/user/hello/other`
This url should load UserDefaultContentComponent: `/user/hello`
Both should load inside the named router-outlet - So in both cases the UserComponent should load.

I get this console output when I am trying to load UserOtherComponent (or any defined subpath):

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'user/hello/other'
>   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'user/hello/other'

While with an empty sub route I get no console error, but the UserComponent isn't loaded. In my own project (Not this reproduction) I get the UserComponent loaded - I can't seem to figure out why the empty path works in my own project. Maybe that information is of help.

EDIT:

Added the missing router-outlet in the app component. Now I am back to the exact issue I have in my full project.

the route `user/user` renders UserDefaultContentComponent. `user/user/other` still doesn't work

Comment: For starters, you are missing the `<router-outlet>` in you `app.component.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your `app.component.html`

**EDIT :**

update your `APP_ROUTES`

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HelloComponent, data: { state: 'home' }},
    { path: 'user', loadChildren: './user-module/user.module#UserModule'}
];
```

and your `USER_ROUTE`

```
const USER_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: ':username', component: UserComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: UserDefaultContentComponent},
      { path: 'other', component: UserOtherComponent},
    ]}
];
```

And replace

```
<router-outlet name="user-outlet"></router-outlet>
```

by

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

[image]

Comment: Removing `outlet` definition courses the sub components to not render. - Keeping them in makes no difference. `UserOtherComponent` still won't load. while `UserDefaultContentComponent` does

Comment: If you have multiple router-outlet, then you can keep the name and add the outlet.
If not, you can remove them from your code (as edited)

Comment: Yes this works!. It seems the named router-outlet broke the output of a named path?? seems like a Angular bug actually. Thx for your time. Do you know if it makes a difference to have the root route defined `user/:username`and the way you did it? with `:username` as root in the child routes