# How do I navigate to a lazy loaded module's child?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, lazy-loading, router-outlet

How do I navigate (or set up) the Angular router so that I navigate a lazy loaded module's child, displaying it to a different router outlet. Below is what I tried; when the EventsModule is loaded the first child (path:''; the event list) should display in the router-outlet named "events" (this works), but when the user clicks on an event, they should be navigated to the second child (path:"eventUid") and the event details component should be displayed instead of the event list. Angular does not recognize this path (e.g. "companyName/events/eventId") and reroutes to the 404 page.

app.module.ts

```
  const appRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: ':company/events', loadChildren: './main/events/events.module#EventsModule' },
      ...
    ];
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

events.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: EventsComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticatedGuard, ActiveGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', component: EventListComponent, outlet: 'events' },
      { path: ':eventUid', component: EventDetailsComponent, outlet: 'events' }
    ]
  }
];
```

events.component.html

```
<nav>...</nav>
<router-outlet name="events"></router-outlet>
```

Please help!

Comment: If Angular pops a 404 error, it means you used the wrong URL. Be sure to use the correct URLS, try using absolute ones to check if it works.

Comment: Hello, can you refere to this question from 1h : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55120494/angular-lazyload-child-routes-with-outlet/55121555#55121555 . You will have stackblitz to help you.

Comment: @trichetriche I have tried to use absolute routes. From me trying to figure out what's going wrong, it seems that the lazy loaded module's children are not loaded as possible routes.

Comment: Have you declared them as `forChild` or `forRoot` ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the solution:

Replaced EventModule's children with:
[{ path: '', component: EventListComponent },
 { path: ':eventUid', component: EventDetailsComponent}]

And removed the "name" attribute from the router-outlet in the events.component.html